# How to get a handle to the sessionStorage using JAVA

Tags: java, xpages, session-storage

I'm looking at a situation that requires a fair bit of data storage that I have considered using sessionScope variables for. In a small test that I ran this worked well, but the data does get written back to the server with each change to the data. I'm considering creating a JAVA bean to update and control the structure of this data and store it in a series of sessionStorage variables. The sessionStorage is easy in CSJS but I'm not sure how to access these variables from a JAVA Bean. 
The application is something like a shopping cart so I would maintain the data in the sessionStorage until the document submit, then load the values into the document and save it and I think this would work best as a JAVA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **sessionStorage** object stores the data for one session in browser window/tab **on client side**.

There is no way to access the sessionStorage from server with Java.

You can though send the data to server and there you can pick it up with Java.

You can send it per Ajax or you can submit it in hidden fields.

If you store a complex data structure with objects and arrays in sessionStorage then you might convert it to JSON as an easy to use transport medium.

You would convert the sessionStorage to a JSON string on client side with

```
JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)
```

You can parse the JSON string with Java on server side with classes from [com.ibm.commons.util.io.json](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/commons/util/io/json/package-summary.html) package

```
JsonJavaFactory factory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
json = (JsonJavaObject) JsonParser.fromJson(factory, jsonString);
```

Comment: Was looking for a way to do this without having to send/receive from the server. Might look at doing it with CSJs but thought it might be nicer in JAVA but perhaps not.

Comment: @BillF as Knut writes the sessionStorage is _local_ in the user's browser. No way for the server to even see that without having to send it back and forth (like for cookies that are part of the requests).

Answer (score 0):

This will get the sessionScope not the localStorage, webstorage, sessionstorage locally in the browser

But if you want sessionScope this is how you do it
Import these two classes

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
```

And then you can get it using this code

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
Map sessionScope = externalContext.getSessionMap();
```

Comment: So the variable sessionScope will contain the contents of the sessionStorage?

Comment: No, sessionScope is a Map on server whereas sessionStorage is an object in browser on client side.